# Receive HttpStatusCode 401 when calling Admob API with .NET client library

Tags: google-api, admob, google-oauth, service-accounts, google-api-dotnet-client

I am writing a C# console program which calls Admob API by using .NET client library. The authentication is done via Service Account.

```
            String serviceAccountEmail = "My service account email";

            var certificate = new X509Certificate2("My p12 file", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);


            ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
               new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
               {
                   Scopes = new[] { AdMobService.ScopeConstants.AdmobReadonly }
               }.FromCertificate(certificate));

            // Create the service.
            var service = new AdMobService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Admob API Sample",
            });

            var accounts = service.Accounts.List().ExecuteAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

When I run the above code block, it raises an exception at the last line:

```
Google.GoogleApiException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=The service admob has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is Unauthorized. Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
  Source=Google.Apis
  StackTrace:
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.<ParseResponse>d__35.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
```

What am I doing wrong?
P/S: My framework is netcoreapp3.1

I 've tried to search for the answers on Google and stack overflow but still not found a solution for it yet. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[Authorization](https://developers.google.com/admob/api/v1/how-tos/authorizing)

[image]

Service accounts would appear to not be supported by that api. Switch to Oauth2.

Comment: Thank you @DalmTo for your prompt response!

Comment: Thank you @DalmTo for your prompt response! My above code is using OAuth 2.0 cause Service Account is just a client type. According to the below link from Google, I think they do support us in authorizing OAuth 2.0 for Service Account:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account

And I had a reference from the below link to write the above code block:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#service-account

Please show me if I am misunderstanding something.

Many thanks,

Comment: @ThiPham not all apis support service account authencation.   If you have found something in the documentation or this api that states it does then i will look into it.  However from what i can see this api does not support service accounts.  The api clearly statues Oauth2 if it supported service accounts it would say that.